# Test listbox component with react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to test the listbox component. I would like to see the option list and be able to select an option. Could you quickly show me or point me to an example of how to test the listbox component?

https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-silence-0rgqw?file=/src/App.test.js

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at this - https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/#selectoptionselement-values

Although looking the DOM of the Listbox (Select) used from `@reach/listbox`, there seems to be **no** "listbox"role on the parent `span`, so you might have to update your selector accordingly.